# frame to frame actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame

Once the raid boss' HP reached '0', the ProtodermisEntity.gotoAndStop(6), and then it moved to another frame. Any ideas how to fix this.

This is an error, TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference at frame 102:192

```
function BarrierHitted(): void {
    currentRaidBossHP -= Math.floor(Math.random()*10001);
    if (currentRaidBossHP <= 0) //if the raid boss died
    {
        ProtodermisEntity.gotoAndStop(6);
        if(ProtodermisEntity.currentFrame == 115){
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopSecret);
            gotoAndStop("gameover_Secret");
            sound_channel.stop();
            return;
        }
    }
    HealthBar(); //update the healthBar
}
```

Then when the HP reaches 0,

```
if (ProtodermisEntity.Aura.hitTestObject(blowfishPong) == true) {
        if (ballSpeedXSecret > 0) {
            ballSpeedXSecret *= -1;
            ballSpeedYSecret = calculateBallAngleSecret(ProtodermisEntity.y, blowfishPong.y);
            DarkAuraHit.play();
            Barrier();
            HealthBar();
            BarrierHitted();
            updateTextFieldsSecret();
        }
    }
```

Comment: **(1)** The compiler tells you that on **frame 102** there is error on **line 192**. What is the **exact code** on line 192? **(2)** If you don't know, a property or method (meaning function) is what comes after the dot in a variable like: `someVar.width` where **width is a property** of the variable, or `someVar.load();` where **load(); is a method** (function) existing inside the variable. On your line 192 you are changing a property or trying to run a function that does not exist in variable/object, or maybe object itself does not exist on frame 192...

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this problem, or do you have your answers?

Comment: What happens if you delete line 192? Does the error go away? I tried to ask you _"What is the exact code on line 192"_ but if you cannot tell us then only you can fix the problem because only you can see line 192...

Comment: if (ProtodermisEntity.Aura.hitTestObject(blowfishPong) == true)

Comment: Before the IF statement, you'll have to add some **trace** to see which object is null (meaning is not existing). Check as: `trace( "blowfishPong is : " + blowfishPong );` and also check as `trace( "ProtodermisEntity is : " + ProtodermisEntity );`. Does it say "Null" or "Undefined" about them?

Comment: blowfishPong is : [object MovieClip]
ProtodermisEntity is : [object ProtodermisEntity_105], then, TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: Check for the "aura" part: `trace( "Aura is : " + ProtodermisEntity.Aura );` if it is said to be an **object** that means no problem with the IF statement and I don't know why compiler would say you are using some unknown variable or function...

Comment: Also in your Question (at top)... Does any of that shown code cause any errors? Does this line work `gotoAndStop("gameover_Secret");`? I wonder why you show that code if the problem was because of other code doing a HitTestObject?

Comment: 1. Aura is : [object MovieClip] until is null, 2. It doesn't work because of this code "ProtodermisEntity.currentFrame"

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work because of this line: `if(ProtodermisEntity.Stunned.currentFrame == 115)`?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem

Comment: Once I reached the HP to 0, it received this TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. And if (ProtodermisEntity.Aura.hitTestObject(blowfishPong) == true) and if (ProtodermisEntity.currentFrame == 115)

Comment: Inside your IF statement, try to **comment** the code by putting `/*` at start and a `*/` to end the commenting. This will disable the code and you can then try testing one line at a time. Should be: `if (currentRaidBossHP <= 0) { /* ProtodermisEntity.gotoAnd ...up to... sound_channel.stop(); */ }` .... After commenting does the error go away? PS: You do not `return` anything so don't need to use return in your shown code.

Comment: It should be ok after I tested.

Comment: If you say `ProtodermisEntity.gotoAndStop(6);` then how can the next line happen? That is `if(ProtodermisEntity.currentFrame == 115)` so what will make `ProtodermisEntity` go to **frame (115)** when, on previous code line, it was actually stopped on **frame (6)**? ... Is there any other code (that you did not show) that is changing the frame numbers of `ProtodermisEntity`?

Comment: Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kX9j-bj7RMzoTQbJ5aF8ZNYQBOcqi4V6/view?usp=sharing.  Refer in the "Main Game" Scene, then, look at the actionscript in "playScreen_Secret"

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I cannot download a quarter of a gigabyte. Too big. I also can't open FLA file. No Flash/Animate IDE... **(1)** Just tell me if `ProtodermisEntity.gotoAndStop(6);` then why next line expects it be not on **frame 6** but instead is magically moved to be now on **frame 115**? Does `ProtodermisEntity` have enough frames to even reach number 115? **(2)** Forget the code you wrote. Explain what you want to happen when `if (currentRaidBossHP <= 0)` then we can see what code should achieve that expected result.

Comment: OK I will try to understand one last time... You have **too much missing information**. Where does `if (ProtodermisEntity.Aura.hitTestObject(blowfishPong) == true)` come from? I mean is it inside some other function you created but did not show?...  Why don't you **just show all the code that works together** instead of just one line? What code makes `BarrierHitted` happen, what code is about `hitTestObject`... This is only a 1-day problem but your minimum info is making it take 17 days to fix a simple thing.

Comment: Your `if (ProtodermisEntity.Aura.hitTestObject(blowfishPong) == true) { ...code... }` will not work correctly like that. You need to **add** an **EnterFrame** event listener and the listening function itself should check the `IF` and `HitTest` situation. Later... before telling `ProtodermisEntity` to go to **frame(6)** you must first also **remove the EnterFrame listener**.